# Is it bad practice to install WordPress by cloning from the official GitHub repo?

Tags: installation, git, github

I haven't found any straight answers in my searches, so I am wondering if anyone could tell me if it's bad practice to clone from the official GitHub repo for WordPress installation.

I'm aware that this will create a .git directory in the htdocs, but I don't know if that is a *bad* thing. (e.g., https://github.com/WordPress/health-check/issues/323)

I'll appreciate any insight!

Comment: In general I would think not - at least, if you're cloning a tagged release (and from the `wordpress/wordpress` repo - not `wordpress/wordpress-develop`). If you just clone `master` you may end up with changesets that haven't officially been distributed which *could* lead to some problems in production environments. It might also be wise to use `--depth 1` to avoid cloning unnecessary history - or download the repo through some other mechanism such as rsync, since you do not actually need any git functionality. But I'm definitely interested in any other insights :)

Comment: Having git directories published publicly in a production environment is a _very_ bad idea: https://threatpost.com/open-git-directories-leave-390k-websites-vulnerable/137299/

Comment: @JacobPeattie Ah, thank you! That's all I needed to see. I'll also keep that in mind with plugins.